# How can I prevent users from submitting URLs in textfields?

Tags: 8, webforms

Is there any way to prevent URLs in the textfields and if present prevent the submission of the form? I was looking around the interface to figure this out. I was looking to check for `http` and `https` in the string.

There's seems to be a way to check for a pattern in the string... but to me it seems to be the exact opposite of what I need. It seems as if you can only check that the string needs to be there. But I want to check that it's not there. How can I do this?

I am on Drupal 8.9.1. and Webform is version 8.x-5.16.

Comment: use `function hook_form_HOOK_ID_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface &$formState){}` in your .theme file. Then attach a validation function to your form `$form['actions']['submit']['#validate'][] = 'example_submission';`. In `example_submission`, check the field against your pattern.

Comment: Honestly I don't understand what the actual problem is and what exactly you want to achieve. Can you maybe update your question to provide more context and samples?

Comment: @leymannx he probably meant to say, it's the reverse the string **does not** need to be there/match.

Comment: @NoSssweat – Ah, so the question maybe is how you can prevent users from entering URLs into textfields? I didn't got that far. I was thinking of link fields or whatever other form fields but not textfields. 

Answer (score 3):

Edit webform element, under form validation, checkmark pattern.

Use a [negative regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408)

Ex: `^(?!:https|http).*$`

[image]

Comment: seems like this works if there is only one paragraph, but if a second paragraph is allowed in the field then it fails. any suggestions?

Comment: ie it fails in a textarea element